# Send the value of a disabled select in a form with a hidden input

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a Django form, one of the parts is populated like this:

```
  <select
     {% if 'ba1' in widget.name or 'bs1' in widget.name or 'pm2' in widget.name %}
     disabled
     {% endif %}
     id="{{ widget.attrs.id }}"
     name="{{ widget.name }}"
     {% if widget.attrs.disabled %}disabled{% endif %}
     {% if widget.required %}required{% endif %}
     class="form-control form-control-sm
        {% if widget.errors %} is-invalid{% else %} is-valid{% endif %}"
     aria-describedby="{{ widget.id }}-help">
     {% for value, label in widget.attrs.choices %}
        {% if value in widget.value %}
           <option value="{{ value }}" selected>{{ label }}</option>
        {% else %}
           <option value="{{ value }}" data="{{widget.value}}">{{ label }}</option>
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

As it is a disabled field for ba1, bs1 and pm2 cases, that information will not be sent in the POST request.

So what I have done is, through a hidden input, send the selected value of the disabled select.

Unfortunately the value is always 0 instead of the correct value. I'm doing something wrong. Somebody could help me?.

For example if the selected value is 2, or 3 or 4, it doesn't matter, the hidden input says that the selected value is 0, which is not correct.

Hidden input code (not working, always value = 0)

```
  {% if 'ba1' in widget.name or 'bs1' in widget.name or 'pm2' in widget.name %}
  <input
     type="hidden"
     name="{{ widget.name }}"
     class="form-control form-control-sm
        {% if widget.errors %} is-invalid{% else %} is-valid{% endif %}"
     {% for value, label in widget.attrs.choices %}
        {% if value in widget.value %}
           value="{{ value }}"
        {% else %}
           value="{{ value }}" data="{{widget.value}}"
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
  >
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Please see how to write a [mre]. How do you set the values for these hidden inputs? How does the server get / read these values (`request.POST` / automatically done by the form class, etc.)? Just the template is obviously not enough to reproduce your problem...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat So the workflow is as follows: 
The user clicks a button, that button calls a view in views.py, that view generates the values of the form and render that values in the response. After the values are rendered in, let's say 'a.html', the user clicks another button that also calls a view in views.py, that view needs to get the previous values of the form rendered at 'a.html' in order to display the same form values in the rendered response  'b.html'. I think that's all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the field as disabled in the init method of that Form class in forms.py.

```
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Yourfield'].disabled = True
```

Comment: But that will apply to all the selects, right? I just want to disable 3 specific selects: ba1, bs2, and pm2.

Comment: No, the fields that you want to disable, specify it explicitly. self.fields['field1'].disabled = True Likewise self.fields['field2'].disabled = True